# when chose radio option calendar show up in search filed

Tags: php, html

I have search form like this :

[Search form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iQJQ.jpg)

code :

```html
<input type="text" name="sign" class="search_text1 " value"" />

<input type="radio" class="search_date1" name="search_by" value=""> Issue Date<br/>
```

I want when user chose radio option , and go click on search filed , calendar show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a jQuery calendar plugin, like [this one](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/).
It has an onShow event, which you can fill with a function, that would check if Issue Date radio is selected.

Comment: I had one before like this http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/  it is work with me , but my question : I want when user chose radio option , and go click on search filed , calendar show up ... some one give me this code:

<script>
$( "#search_date1" ).click(function() {
  $("#search_text1" ).addId( "datepicker" );
});
</script>

but not working with me

Comment: to explain : I have like this form :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxHXJvjS6gELTFFUbk1yT0xzTzA/view
and I want when user chose radio option , and go click on search filed , calendar show up , when user chose radio option
thanx

Comment: I'm not going to do it all for you, this is basic, stuff. You need to learn events and how to work with them. In your case, you  need to bind a click event (https://api.jquery.com/click/) to that radio option, which would then open the calendar, or display a previously rendered calendar. Read through that article, there are examples, and you will learn how to do that yourself for the next time :)